# Does any other clustering algorithms take correlation as distance metric (apart from Hierachical)?

Tags: clustering, python, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

I have used correlation metric as distance measure for hierachical clustering and obtained the clusters. I used scikit (python 3.5) for clustering hierachical cluster.

Now, I want to use another clustering algorithm with same dataset.

I am not sure whether any other clustering algorithms will take correlation as distance metric.

I request you to assist with which algorithms are feasible for this ? and How can I use it.

Comment: Almost every algorithm except k-means and GMM. Have a look at ELKI, it includes correlation (maybe even with index for acceleration!) and several clustering algorithms such as DBSCAN, OPTICS, HDBSCAN*, that can be used with correlation distance.

Comment: You are right. Those are implemented in JAVA. 
Can you assist me with Python implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From scikit-learn, any clustering that can work with "precomputed" distances should work. For example, [Affinity Propagation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html#sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation) or [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html).

(To be clear, you have to first calculate the pairwise distance matrix between your data points and then use this matrix as input)

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, So instead of dataset I should give correlation(distance metric) as input ?

Comment: Yes, first you use `dist=sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(data)` to calculate the distance matrix from your data, and then you use the resulting `dist` object as input to the clustering algorithms, remembering to select the option `affinity="precomputed` for affinity propagation or `metric="precomputed"` in the case of DBSCAN. BTW for affinity propagation I think you need to transform the distances into similarities.

Comment: **dist=sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(data)**

Does this correlate dataset with each other ?

Comment: Each element of your data set with each other, yes. Suppose your data set are N rows (samples) with M columns (dimensions, features). then `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(data, metric="correlation")` will return a matrix of size NxN with the correlation distances between the elements. (I assumed this is how you obtained the distances inthe first place.)

Comment: Thanks Leo,My dataset is of 1000 variables. and each dataset is measured for 50,000 time  intervals.

So dataset looks like matrix of 50,000 rows and 1000 columns

Comment: I am experimenting with the dist as you suggested `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(data, metric="correlation")` and correlation obtained using formula method. However dist forms the better cluster result for Affinity Propagation algorithm. 

Could you please guide me on this

Comment: From what I understand it is better if you create another question, linking to this one here. Your new question will appear on main page and more people will try to help you, people more qualified than me.  (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions).